# unable to establish socket connection to the server on college lan

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to make a program in which a client simply makes a socket connection to the server both present on the same college LAN.

This is the server code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ChatServer
{
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        try 
        {
            ServerSocket ssoc=new ServerSocket(4242);
            Socket sock=ssoc.accept();
            PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            writer.println("Hello there");
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Message sent");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

This is the client code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client
{
    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s=new Socket("172.16.12.124",4242); 

            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader StreamReader=new BufferedReader(reader);
            String ad=StreamReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(ad);
            StreamReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Client cl=new Client();
        cl.go();
    }
}
```

I am using my laptop as server. The problem is that the program works fine when client connects to the hotspot created on the server(my laptop). But when  I try to connect it over college LAN then it does not works. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That could be a firewall (or some other network filtering) issue.  Have you tried using some standard ports, like 23, 25, 53, 80, or 443?  Or maybe 1389?

Comment: but aren't those reserved ports??

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean you can't use them.  It depends on if there's another process using that port and whether your account has permissions.  If Question 1 is "No" and Question 2 is "Yes" then there's no reason why you can't.

Comment: I should qualify my comment... edit it to saying "then there's *probably* no reason why you can't."